# Can I recover anything from a crashed Tableau server?

Tags: tableau-api

My Tableau server ran out of disk space and now is irrecoverable.  Multiple services won't start and I've been told it is time to move on and rebuild the server.

However before I do this, I wondered whether I can recover any of my work (workbooks, calculated fields, parameters) from the file system, or by connecting directly to the underlying PostgreSQL instance?  I've tried the tabcmd commands but they rely on services that cannot be started.

I'm not necessarily looking for an output that can be imported into my new instance (although that would be great), more just some reminders of how I got past some of the trickier problems I faced.

Comment: Often you can mount a disk in another system and read files from it.

Comment: Thanks - specifically, where am I looking in the schema/file system to get back anything useful?

Comment: You might have to recognize your own directory structure or filenames. Of course, it would be easier to use your latest backup.